# Laser Iridium spark plug gap for 2012 f-150 5.0 liter

Tags: ford, f-150

I am replacing my plugs in my 2012 f-150 5.0 truck with NGK laser iridium spark plugs.  what it the correct gap? I see many different answers on the internet.

Comment: So any answer you get here will also be "on the internet" right?  Did you check your Owner's Manual?

Comment: I'd think the NGK site would be authoritative.  https://www.ngk.com/product.aspx?zpid=40122

Comment: Plugs are pre-gapped these days, trying to adjust this on that type of plug Will Damage it!

Answer (score 1):

[RockAuto.com](https://www.rockauto.com/en/catalog/ford,2012,f-150,5.0l+v8,3015601,ignition,spark+plug,7212) shows the gap for the two different NGK Iridium plugs listed (95853 & 6509) for your F-150 5.0 to be 0.052".

With that in mind, most plugs of this type are set from the factory. They'll usually state "Do Not Gap" on the box. Ensure you check to see if this is true with your plugs before you start bending on things.